# Problems with if else with multiple test conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe ("daily") simplified as follow:

Day Spot
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6

I want a new column, treatment, whose elements should be factors "ambient" (spots 2,3,6) and "elevated" (spots 1, 4, 5). I have tried this:

```
daily$treatment<- factor(ifelse(daily$ring==c("1","4","5"), "elevated", "ambient"))
```

But it returned this warnings, and the result is not what I need:
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(daily$ring, c("1", "4", "5")) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Alternatively I have also tried, but nothing:

```
if (daily$ring==1 | daily$ring==4 | daily$ring==5){
   daily$treatment <- "elevated"
 } else {
   daily$treatment <- "ambient"
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You are looking for `%in%`...

Comment: Also, the problem with your second snippet of code is that `if` and `else` are not vectorized (you would have to do `for(i in 1:nrow(daily))...` if you wanted that version to work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
daily$treatment <- factor(ifelse(daily$Spot %in% c(1,4,5), "elevated", "ambient"))

daily
##   Day Spot treatment
## 1   1    1  elevated
## 2   1    2   ambient
## 3   1    3   ambient
## 4   1    4  elevated
## 5   1    5  elevated
## 6   1    6   ambient
```

Comment: A little more succinctly, `daily = transform(daily, treatment = ifelse(Spot %in% c(1, 4, 5), "elevated", "ambient"))`